# Free Asp.net CMS with basic module

Tags: content-management-system

I am looking for good Asp.net CMS (like wordpress) with some modules like News and media, Photo gallery, Form.
I checked DotNetNuke site but not able to get difference between Community edition and professional edition.

Can anyone suggest any good CMS?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

refer to this link for your answers

http://www.dotnetnukeprofessional.co.uk/products/version-comparison